# Windows Powershell thinks Desktop does not exist

Tags: windows, powershell, path

I need to change directories. However, when I run the command, the Powershell throws an error, saying it could not find the path because it does not exist.

Here is the error thrown when I run the prompt:
[image: error]

I tried using `cd` to change directories and made the path Desktop however these attempts did not work. I am unaware if this is a syntax error, or if it is an external error.

Comment: You do not have permission to access the folder.  Only the user and an admin has the access to the folder. The ~ only works on linux not windows.

Comment: @jdweng, (a) If this were a permissions problem - it isn't - the error message would be different ("Access denied"). (b) The user at hand is trying to access *their own* desktop folder. (c) `~` is supported _by PowerShell_, on all platforms, namely as a _provider feature_. The `FileSystem` provider resolves it to the current user's home folder, analogous to POSIX-compatible shells (where it is a feature of the _shell itself_, however).

Comment: Your desktop directory may be mapped to a different location. What does `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')` report? If you believe it should be `$HOME\Desktop`, after all, try creating it: `New-Item -Type Directory $HOME\Desktop`

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is much appreciated! Sorry for the bad post, I am fairly new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: No worries, glad to hear we could help. So how did you end up solving your problem?

Comment: I had to include OneDrive in the directory, so it was cd ~/OneDrive/Desktop